# Dealing with Varying Data Types WIth C# Database.SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, postgresql

I'm using .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 6.

I have to use a pre-built SQL string and execute it against a PostgreSQL database. I'm currently using [DBContext].Database.SqlQuery() to pull these values, but I have a mix of int and double values that are returned depending on which field in the table is pulled. I keep getting type cast exceptions because I'm trying to force the int to be a another type like float or double through the SqlQuery call. I've tried varying combinations of the following, but haven't had any luck.

```
//db is my database context
var queryResult = db.Database.SqlQuery<float>(queryString);

//Extract and cast the value from the query result
//Works fine until a field with a type of int is encountered
tagValue = (float)auxQuery.Single();

//I've also tried this with <dynamic> in place of <float> above.
//tagValue = Convert.ChangeType(queryResult.Single(), typeof(float));
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? It seems like there should be a clean way of doing this without adding extra logic to try to determine the field type ahead of time.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you process this field by field?

Comment: have you thought about Converting it vs Casting it for example 
`Convert.ToSingle()` Method

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't know which fields are going to be accessed in the SQL string that I'm passed.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Do I use the dynamic type with that Convert? When I do I get the following exception.

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

Here's the two lines involved now.

`var auxQuery = db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(auxQueryStr);

tagValue = Convert.ToDouble(auxQuery.Single());`